# Cannot ping or access webserver

Tags: iptables, webserver, ping, hostapd

I have a kali chroot running on my phone which has a custom kernel that includes external usb wifi adapter drivers. Inside the chroot, I'm using hostapd to create an AP and isc-dhcp-server for DHCP. I'm also hosting a page using lighttpd. The AP gets created successfully and clients can connect to it. Dhcp assigns IP.

**The problem I'm facing**

I can neither ping the AP ip address from any connected clients nor can i ping from AP to a client. I've flushed all iptables rules and set them to allow everything. Still i cannot even ping the server. The connected clients can ping each other though but not the AP hosted by hostapd. I want to connect to the webserver.

```
root@kali:/home# ip r
192.169.1.0/24 dev wlan1mon proto kernel scope link src 192.169.1.1
```

```
root@kali:/home#ip a
31: wlan1mon: <BROADCAST,ALLMULTI,PROMISC,NOTRAILERS,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether a8:49:4d:2f:ba:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.169.1.1/24 scope global wlan1mon
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::aa49:4dff:fe2f:ba3c/64 scope link valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
32: mon2: <BROADCAST,ALLMULTI,PROMISC,NOTRAILERS,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000 link/ieee802.11/radiotap ec:08:6b:18:f5:9c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

```
root@kali:/home# ip -4 neigh
192.169.1.33 dev wlan1mon lladdr 76:ed:ff:f6:28:cd STALE
```

I can provide more information if you want. Struggling with this for a long time. Don't know how to debug.